# How to pass values between controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to share an array between controller methods and store it until page reloads or calling method of another controller? Some methods should change the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to share the value across the methods of a same controller instance then,
declare an instance variable:

```
class BarsController < UsersController

  before_filter :init_foo_list

  def method1
    render :method2
  end 

  def method2
    @foo_list.each do | item|
      # do something
   end
  end

  def init_foo_list
    @foo_list ||= ['Money', 'Animals', 'Ummagumma']
  end

end
```

If you want to share the value across two controllers withn a session, then:

```
class BarsController < UsersController

  before_filter :init_foo_list

  def method1
    render :controller => "FoosController", :action => "method2"
  end 

  def init_foo_list
    params[:shared_param__] ||= ['Money', 'Animals', 'Ummagumma']
  end    
end

class FoosController < UsersController

  def method2
    params[:shared_param__].each do | item|
      # do something
   end
  end
end
```

Give an unique name to the shared parameter key so as to avoid collision with existing keys.

Other option is to store the shared array in the session ad delete it before the final render.

Comment: attr_accessor means that I can access this variable all over the class instance. Hmm..  I'll try this! Thanks!

Comment: First way not working. foo_list is nil in method2
But the first method is called before the second.
And how can I define foo_list not in methods but on initialize?

    def initialize
      self.foo_list = ['Money', 'Animals', 'Ummagumma']
    end
In this way or somehow in another way?

Comment: Set the value in  a `before_filter`

Comment: Not working. The value of @foo_list lost between actions. I've set initial value in before filter, then I've changed it's value in method1, and in method2 it has the same value as defined in before filter.
In before filter I've set:
    @foo_list ||= [0]
Than im my create action:
    @foo_list << 1
In my update_list action it has [0] value.

Comment: To preserve the value across the sessions declare the variable as class variable instead of instance variable (i,e. `@@foo_list` instead of `@foo_list`)

Comment: At last it works. It works only with config.cache_classes = true.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Rails reloads the classes for every request in `development` mode.

Answer (score 6):

you can use rails cache.

```
Rails.cache.write("list",[1,2,3])
Rails.cache.read("list")
```

Comment: Your way seems to be working! I didn't found a good docs for Rails.cache can you provide me a link please.

Comment: But what happens when different sessions have different values?

Comment: I second `Tony`. Unless you ensure the uniqueness of the `list` name across the session this solution will fail during concurrent requests.

Comment: My situation was a little different from the OP, but this solved a problem I was working on beautifully.

Comment: This was perfect for me.  I had two controller actions, the first submits a form and then redirects to the second which is a summary - I needed to get the ids of all of the entries created by the first controller to render those entries as a summary on the second controller's view.  I put the ids into an instance variable as an array, wrote that to the cache, then read it in the next view.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether my answer is close to your requirement, but this is what I do if I want to get the value of an object/model which is fetched in one controller action and basis on that value I need to  fetch other values in another controller action.
I make use of **class variables** and use it throughout my controller action

for eg:

```
@pages=Post.find.all`

@@my_value=@pages.(any manipulations)
```

now `@@my_vales` can be used in any actions of that controller..

hope it helps...